# Reading binary data into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some binary data and I was wondering how I can load that into pandas.

Can I somehow load it specifying the format it is in, and what the individual columns are called?

**Edit:**
Format is

```
int, int, int, float, int, int[256]
```

each comma separation represents a column in the data, i.e. the last 256 integers is one column.

Comment: you need to put it into a numpy array (or python dict/list). is it a custom format? or something like stata?

Comment: It's a custom format. Some integers, some floats.

Comment: your best bet is prob just read with python and create a numpy array; if speed is a problem, then u can read with cython, or if u already have a reader in c then u can wrap in cython

Comment: Can provide the format of you binary file?

Comment: Sure. Added the format to the original post.

Comment: Can something be done without providing format? i.e. if I have more than a thousand columns, it would take a while and unnecessary effort.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Even though this is an old question, I was wondering the same thing and I didn't see a solution I liked.

When reading binary data with Python I have found `numpy.fromfile` or `numpy.fromstring` to be much faster than using the Python struct module. Binary data with mixed types can be efficiently read into a numpy array, using the methods above, as long as the data format is constant and can be described with a numpy data type object (`numpy.dtype`).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a dtype with the binary data format and the desired column names
dt = np.dtype([('a', 'i4'), ('b', 'i4'), ('c', 'i4'), ('d', 'f4'), ('e', 'i4'),
               ('f', 'i4', (256,))])
data = np.fromfile(file, dtype=dt)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Or if you want to explicitly set the column names
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.dtype.names)
```

**Edits:**

- Removed unnecessary conversion of `data.to_list()`. Thanks fxx
- Added example of leaving off the `columns` argument

Comment: A great improvement. Thanks for posting this solution.

Comment: The list conversion is unnecessary, using data directly as driver for the Pandas dataframe speeds things up: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.dtype.names)

Comment: Can something be done without providing format? i.e. if I have more than a thousand columns, it would take a while and unnecessary effort.

Comment: I cannot directly convert the numpy array to Dataframe, it raises: `ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional, got ndarray of shape (6059, 1) instead`, even the numpy array is 1D (`shape=(6059,)`).  I ended up satisfied with numpy array itself, as I can retrieve data with syntax like `data[:]['f']`.

Answer (score 16):

Recently I was confronted to a similar problem, with a much bigger structure though. I think I found an improvement of mowen's answer using utility method *DataFrame.from_records*. In the example above, this would give:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a dtype with the binary data format and the desired column names
dt = np.dtype([('a', 'i4'), ('b', 'i4'), ('c', 'i4'), ('d', 'f4'), ('e', 'i4'), ('f', 'i4', (256,))])
data = np.fromfile(file, dtype=dt)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

In my case, it significantly sped up the process. I assume the improvement comes from not having to create an intermediate Python list, but rather directly create the DataFrame from the Numpy structured array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to get you started.

```
from struct import unpack, calcsize
from pandas import DataFrame

entry_format = 'iiifi256i' #int, int, int, float, int, int[256]
field_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', ]
entry_size = calcsize(entry_format)

with open(input_filename, mode='rb') as f:
    entry_count = os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size / entry_size
    for i in range(entry_count):
        record = f.read(entry_size)
        entry = unpack(entry_format, record)
        entry_frame = dict( (n[0], n[1]) for n in zip(field_names, entry) )
        DataFrame(entry_frame)
```

Comment: With minor modifications to your snippet (like `open(.., mode='rb')` and `os.fstat(input_filename)`) I get the following error, `DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Comment: Don't really need to get the count here.... `for record in iter(lambda: f.read(entry_size), ''): # ...` will do it

Comment: This gives an error: `ValueError: If use all scalar values, must pass index`, and it seems like 'f' is 0 and not an array.

Comment: Cool, the struct module looks very useful. I would just append the `entry_frame` dictionaries to a list and then create a DataFrame from a list of dicts after the whole file is read.

Answer (score 1):

The following uses a compiled struct, which is a lot faster than a normal struct. 
An alternative is to use np.fromstring or np.fromfile, as mentioned above.

```
import struct, ctypes, os
import numpy as np, pandas as pd 

mystruct = struct.Struct('iiifi256i')
buff = ctypes.create_string_buffer(mystruct.size)
with open(input_filename, mode='rb') as f:
    nrows = os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size / entry_size
    dtype = 'i,i,i,d,i,i8'
    array = np.empty((nrows,), dtype=dtype)
    for row in xrange(row):
        buff.raw = f.read(s.size)
        record = mystruct.unpack_from(buff, 0)
        #record = np.fromstring(buff, dtype=dtype)
        array[row] = record
 df = pd.DataFrame(array)
```

see also http://pymotw.com/2/struct/