# Accessing android sensor .dat files with both the console and in a text editor through Python for EDA

Tags: python, pandas

NEW PROGRAMMER, please help.

Recently I have been provided a challenge to aid in the refresh and expansion of my python programing skills towards app development and ML.
I have been provided android sensor .dat files. In order to access them I must use the pandas library. However I do not recall the precise part of the library to access and clean the data for EDA to proceed.

My colleague provided MATLAB script which I have zero experience with, and was unable to translate or read (beyond just running it in MATLAB) to access the files, listed below.

```matlab
    function [d] = get_file_data(file_path)
    
    disp(file_path)
    
    file = dir(file_path);
    
    fid = fopen(file_path, 'r');
    
    subfolders = strsplit(file.folder, filesep);
    subfolder = subfolders(end);
    
    [start_time, start_nano_time] = get_filename_times(file.name);
    
    d = [];
    
    if file.bytes == 0
        fprintf('warning: empty file: %s\n', file_path);
     return
    end
    
    if strcmp(subfolder, "accelerometer") == 1
        packets = floor(file.bytes / (8+3*4));
        d = zeros(packets, 4);
    
     for l = 1:packets
            time = fread(fid, 1, 'int64', 'b');
            xyz = fread(fid, 3, 'single', 'b');
            d(l, 1) = start_time + (time - start_nano_time)/1e6;
            d(l, 2) = xyz(1);
            d(l, 3) = xyz(2);
            d(l, 4) = xyz(3);
     end
    elseif strcmp(subfolder, "gravity") == 1
        packets = floor(file.bytes / (8+3*4));
        d = zeros(packets, 4);
    
     for l = 1:packets
            time = fread(fid, 1, 'int64', 'b');
            xyz = fread(fid, 3, 'single', 'b');
            d(l, 1) = start_time + (time - start_nano_time)/1e6;
            d(l, 2) = xyz(1);
            d(l, 3) = xyz(2);
            d(l, 4) = xyz(3);
     end
    elseif strcmp(subfolder, "gyroscope") == 1
        packets = floor(file.bytes / (8+3*4));
        d = zeros(packets, 4);
    
     for l = 1:packets
            time = fread(fid, 1, 'int64', 'b');
            xyz = fread(fid, 3, 'single', 'b');
            d(l, 1) = start_time + (time - start_nano_time)/1e6;
            d(l, 2) = xyz(1);
            d(l, 3) = xyz(2);
            d(l, 4) = xyz(3);
     end
    elseif strcmp(subfolder, "light") == 1
        packets = floor(file.bytes / (8+1*4));
        d = zeros(packets, 2);
     
     for l = 1:packets
            time = fread(fid, 1, 'int64', 'b');
            x = fread(fid, 1, 'single', 'b');
            d(l, 1) = start_time + (time - start_nano_time)/1e6;
            d(l, 2) = x;
     end
    elseif strcmp(subfolder, "magnetic_field") == 1
        packets = floor(file.bytes / (8+3*4));
        d = zeros(packets, 4);
     
     for l = 1:packets
            time = fread(fid, 1, 'int64', 'b');
            xyz = fread(fid, 3, 'single', 'b');
            d(l, 1) = start_time + (time - start_nano_time)/1e6;
            d(l, 2) = xyz(1);
            d(l, 3) = xyz(2);
            d(l, 4) = xyz(3);
     end
    elseif strcmp(subfolder, "pressure") == 1
        packets = floor(file.bytes / (8+1*4));
        d = zeros(packets, 2);
    
     for l = 1:packets
            time = fread(fid, 1, 'int64', 'b');
            x = fread(fid, 1, 'single', 'b');
            d(l, 1) = start_time + (time - start_nano_time)/1e6;
            d(l, 2) = x;
     end
    elseif strcmp(subfolder, "proximity") == 1
        packets = floor(file.bytes / (8+1*4));
        d = zeros(packets, 2);
     
     for l = 1:packets
            time = fread(fid, 1, 'int64', 'b');
            x = fread(fid, 1, 'single', 'b');
            d(l, 1) = start_time + (time - start_nano_time)/1e6;
            d(l, 2) = x;
     end
    elseif strcmp(subfolder, "step_detector") == 1
        packets = floor(file.bytes / 8);
        time = fread(fid, packets, 'int64', 'b');
        d = start_time + (time - start_nano_time)/1e6;
    end
    
    fclose(fid);
    
    d(:, 1) = d(:, 1)./1e3;
    d = sortrows(d);
    
    end
```

Is there a Python analog which anyone could recommend?

Here is what I have found and attempted without success thus far:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html

Code attempt below:

```py
    file = open("C:/Users/CSAS/Desktop/Files!/DS-Materials/sensor-data/c-39db1919-6fff-4229-9ee8-c7b13f882f59/sensor/accelerometer/1654736675164-3669968901397.dat", "rb")
    file.read()
    file.close()
    print(file)
    data =  pd.read_table('~/c-39db1919-6fff-4229-9ee8-c7b13f882f59/sensor/accelerometer/1654736675164-3669968901397.dat', encoding=('ISO-8859-1'), low_memory=False, error_bad_lines=False, lineterminator='\n')
    data
```

which reads as this when printed, however any removal from the pr.read line ends in an error.

Unnamed: 0=\…ÅÀÙˆA—0ó=R¸¶ÀÏºA—NaN1‚=WŸ>ÀÙˆA”žNaN2‰A—NaN3‰A”žNaN4‰A ÞNaN.........118‰AŠÐNaN119¸=K^ìÀöïAŠÐNaN120g^=R¸¶ÀÙˆA·î=R¸¶ÀÏºAŠÐ121Øÿó=WŸ>ÀÏºAˆ]NaN122l=U+úÀ¼ A·&=PEsÀãUAD
123 rows × 2 columns

Is supposed to look like this with the correct syntax ofc:

```
ACCELEROMETER(Sensor, TYPE,_ACCELEROMETER, Sensor, STRING_TYPE_ACELEROMETER, 8+3*4),
AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE(Sensor, TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE, Sensor, STRING_TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE, 8+1*4).
GRAVITY(Sensor,TYPE_GRAVITY, Sensor, STRING_TYPE_GRAVITY, 8+3*4),
```

so further.. with the other sensors.

Here are a few links which have provided insight indeed, though for files not like this one;
[Reading binary data into pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573089/reading-binary-data-into-pandas)

Finally my colleague (without giving away the answer) gave me this hint in their command console, albiet they are on MacOS not Windows such as I am.

```
accelerometer od -x 1654615941248-16438637157.dat | more
```

Comment: The matlab script is written in c when opened in a text editor. Any advice on the problem itself though?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).